# Web API to pass values to the web page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an web page to which I dont have access to the source code. I will need to create an API that will pass auto generated values to the Text box on the page. As I dont have access to the source code of the page, not sure how I will be able to pass the auto generated values through the API.

[image]

When I right click I get the source of the field like below

```
<div class="OneColTable">
  <table class="DataInputTable">
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2"><h3>Enter Project Information</h3><br/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="label">Project name:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="project.name" value="" class="RequiredField"></td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
```

I have create an WEb API before but not sure how to approach this scenario. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The page would have to call the API.  If you don't have access to the source for the page, you won't be able to accomplish this.

Comment: If you don't control the web page then you can't change what the web page does.  You'll need to work with whoever does control it.

Comment: How about having a script that will call the API that will set up the value for the text box. Is it not  possible?. I am new to these and not sure

Comment: And what would load that script?  You've already said you don't control the page.

Comment: Yes we dont have access to the source code. Is there any other way of handling this.

Comment: To repeat myself, "If you don't have access to the source for the page, you won't be able to accomplish this."